# Can a Returned Return again?

Tags: cosmere, warbreaker

In Warbreaker, people who die noble or brave deaths become Returned not surprisingly they return to the world and are considered gods. The Returned can choose to give up his life with their Divine Breath to help a particular person or problem.

My question is, suppose a Returned would give his Divine Breath, thereby dying a noble and brave death, would he be able to Return again?

Comment: Daniel Jackson ascended so often that they stopped doing memorial services for him.

Comment: Depends on if Hoid or Kelsier are in town.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be technically possible, but most likely will never actually happen. People Return not because they die bravely or heroically, as even babies are known to have Returned. Lightsong acquired his title of "The Bold" because he had died heroically, unlike the other Returned who had died in other ways.

People Return through the intervention of Endowment, which is the shard present on Nalthis, the world on which Warbreaker takes place.  Endowment seems to be like Harmony and Ruin on Scadriel (Mistborn) in that a personality with a purpose had become attached to the shard. It seems in death the Returned are given a vision of the future by Endownment that they would have the ability to change for the better, and the choice to Return. Once they Return, they cannot remember this mission, however.

Therefore, while I don't know of a reason why they couldn't Return again through the intervention of Endowment, I doubt that Endowment would ever choose to have someone Return more than once.

Comment: Probably only if a higher power than Endowment deemed it necessary - namely, Brandon Sanderson :-)

Comment: "_Therefore, while I don't know of a reason why they couldn't Return again through the intervention of Endowment, I doubt that Endowment would ever choose to have someone Return more than once._"  Didn't we get a whole novel explaining in detail how Lightsong deserves it, for both entertainment and courageous reasons?